# Imprimir un Json en Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, json, eloquent

Me estoy volviendo loco, hace mucho que no trabajaba con archivos *Json* y prácticamente olvide como hacerlo.

Desde *Laravel* estoy haciendo una consulta, y quiero devolver lo de la consulta esto como un *JSON*.

```
public function edit($id){
  
    $Medico = Medicos::all()->where('ID',$id)->toJson();

    return Response()->json($Medico);
  }
```

Estoy haciendo la petición con un *httpRequest* desde *Javascript*:

```
 function cargarModal(){
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "/Medicos/1/edit";
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status == 200) {
            let Medico = this.responseText;
            
            console.log(Medico);
        }
    }
    http.open('GET', url);
    http.send();
}
```

En la consola me devuelve un *Json*, pero raro...

```
"[{\"ID\":1,\"centromedico_id\":1,\"user_id\":1,\"especialidad_id\":1,\"nombre\":\"Pepito\",\"apellidos\":\"Perez\",\"carnet\":1037,\"fechanacimiento\":\"199-02-30\",\"telefono\":75875,\"fichas\":10,\"created_at\":null,\"updated_at\":null}]"
```

> **Digo raro**, porque no recuerdo que un *Json* lleve las barras invertidas.

El problema es que no se como hacer para imprimir los datos, o sea, no se como imprimir el nombre, el apellido, el carnet y así... estuve buscando información, pero nada me funciona, no se que estoy haciendo mal. Ayuda porfa.

Comment: Se ve así porque esta como string, debes convertirlo a un objeto primero. Prueba con `JSON.parse(tu_json)`

Comment: Genial, si funcionó, y a riesgo de parecer un p*ndej*, como imprimo solo el atributo 'nombre' del objeto?

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, porque me resolviste el problema <3

Comment: En el backend lo estás parseando a json dos veces, primero haces `->toJson();` en la colección y luego haces `response()->json()`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias bro, ese era uno de los problemas que tenia y no me habia dado cuenta. Me salvaste

Comment: Bueno, tienes un par de problemas más ahí. Por ejemplo en la eficiencia de la consulta, ya que consultas todos los registros de la tabla y luego filtras por el campo `ID`, si quieres un sólo registro bastaría con `Medicos::find($id);`. Otra cosa es que típicamente el nombre de los modelos es un sustatantivo en singular, o sea `Medico` y no `Medicos`. También en la sintaxis, ya que `Response()` sólo te va a funcionar en windows, la sintaxis es `response()` en minúsculas. Finalmente todo eso lo podrías resumir en `return response()->json(Medicos::find($id)->toArray());`

Comment: Genial, eso si es un gran aporte, muchas gracias bro, lo voy a tomar mucho en cuenta desde ahora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El valor que estas retornando desde tu API esta como texto (`responseText`) para utilizarlo en javascript debes primero convertirlo a objeto con `JSON.parse(tu_json)`.

Ya convertido en objeto puede acceder a sus datos normalmente como accedes a las propiedades de un objeto, ejemplo:

```js
var responseText = "[{\"ID\":1,\"centromedico_id\":1,\"user_id\":1,\"especialidad_id\":1,\"nombre\":\"Pepito\",\"apellidos\":\"Perez\",\"carnet\":1037,\"fechanacimiento\":\"199-02-30\",\"telefono\":75875,\"fichas\":10,\"created_at\":null,\"updated_at\":null}]"

var parsedJson = JSON.parse(responseText)

// Como tu API devuelve un array entonces accedes a la variable como tal.
console.log(parsedJson[0].nombre)
```

Comment: Tengo un problema, el resultado me devuelve un _Undefined_ :(

Comment: Lo mas seguro es que estés accediendo a alguna propiedad que no existe, realiza un log al json y comparte lo que te muestra.

Comment: Recien vi el comentario de @porloscerros Ψ , el tenia razon, lo estaba parseando dos veces en mi backend. Ese era el problema... 
Ya esta resuelto, muchas gracias.